# Wine claims Nvidia OpenGL Drivers not installed correctly?

Tags: nvidia, 12.04, wine, opengl

It seems like wine doesn't see the Nvidia propretary drivers properly.

When I try to launch `wine ~/.wine/drive_c/windows/system32/dxdiag.exe`, Dxdiag crashes immediately. It says it has problems with directx.

In the terminal, I found this error message:

> "err:winediag:X11DRV_WineGL_InitOpenglInfo Direct rendering is
>   disabled, most likely your OpenGL drivers haven't been installed
>   correctly (using GL renderer "GeForce GTX 470/PCIe/SSE2", version "1.4
>   (2.1.2 NVIDIA 295.40)")."

And with `glxinfo | grep "OpenGL version` I receive:

> OpenGL version string: 4.2.0 NVIDIA 295.40

Anyone has any idea about this problem?

PS: I use Blender and the 3d performances are perfect.

Comment: I have solved, it was a update problem, after i updated the entire system wine have seen the opengl drivers!